# Apach Superset [v2.0.0]: Row Level Security - Not working in SQL Lab

Tags: apache-superset

How do we get ROW LEVEL SECURITY working in Superset [v2.0.0]?

I tried many thing but last I am stuck with getting it work within SQL Lab. See bug:https://github.com/apache/superset/issues/20774

If I set RLS_IN_SQLLAB = True within superset/config.py and try to run a query SELECT * FROM FLIGHTS, it tries to pick the WHERE clause "AIRLINE" = 'AS' but still fails due to prefixing it with public.flights.AIRLINE which is not a valid Column name.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Lab in Apache superset does not support row-level security. SQL lab is meant for superadmins who have access to all data.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any official reference, please

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).